How to exclude io.micronaut.docker from io.micronaut.application plugin
I have below plugins in build.gradle file.
plugins {
id 'com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api' version '9.3.1'
id 'io.micronaut.application' version '3.7.2'
}

But I am getting below error.
`
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.micronaut.application', version: '3.7.2']

Failed to apply plugin class 'io.micronaut.gradle.docker.MicronautDockerPlugin'.
Cannot add extension with name 'docker', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
`

I am trying to remove the io.micronaut.docker plugin from io.micronaut.application plugin but it seems that I am not able to do it.
I want to use io.micronaut:micronaut-management package which seems to be there only in the io.micronaut.application package. io.micronaut.minimal.application does not have that
I have tried to use the io.micronaut.minimal.application plugin but I am getting below error.
:cndbtier:db_mgr_svcs:db_replication_svc:test: Could not find io.micronaut:micronaut-inject:.

buildscript {
    ext {
        micronautVersion="3.7.2"
    }
    repositories {
        
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id("io.micronaut.minimal.application") version "${micronautVersion}"
    id("io.micronaut.aot") version "${micronautVersion}"
    id("io.micronaut.graalvm") version "${micronautVersion}"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

buildImage.onlyIf { false }
pushImage.onlyIf { false }

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.oracle.cgbu.*")
    }
    aot {
        optimizeServiceLoading = true
        convertYamlToJava = false
        precomputeOperations = true
        cacheEnvironment = true
        optimizeClassLoading = true
        deduceEnvironment = true
        optimizeNetty = true
    }
}


subprojects {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"
    apply plugin: "io.micronaut.minimal.application"
    
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
    targetCompatibility = '17'
 
    dependencies {

        implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty"
        implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
        implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject"
        implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
        implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-security"
        implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-aop"
        implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-jdbc"
        implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-logback"
        implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime"
        implementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5"
        implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    }
}


What precisely do you mean by "io.micronaut:micronaut-actuator package"? I can find no reference to it.

Sorry I was trying to use io.micronaut:micronaut-management package.
 plugins {
     id("io.micronaut.minimal.application") version "${micronautVersion}"
     id("io.micronaut.aot") version "${micronautVersion}"
     id("io.micronaut.graalvm") version "${micronautVersion}"
 }

subprojects {

    apply plugin: "io.micronaut.minimal.application"

    sourceCompatibility = '17'

    targetCompatibility = '17'

    dependencies {

        implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-management"

        implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime:${micronautVersion}")


Right, well if you use the code you've just written then you are adding the io.micronaut:micronaut-management package. Please revisit and amend your question to make clear what your issue is.

I have added the full build.gradle file, Can you please take a look.

Thanks. I've checked it pretty carefully and I can't find the reason for the error. The minimal application plugin code applies the micronaut component plugin, which applies the micronaut BOM to implementation, and micronaut-inject is part of the BOM, so all seems ok. If I had your problem, I would now be resorting to debugging the build, or applying a workaround (eg the BOM is added in an afterEvaluate hook, which can be buggy, so you could try manually adding the BOM to implementation)

Thank you very much @SimonJacobs .. after following your suggestion It is working now.
I have also removed "micronautVersion=3.7.2" line from the gradle.properties. I'm not sure if that has significance here.
